# Spring controller - logging request and response body

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I have a spring application which exchanges JSON with the mobile.
Spring controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
public String register(@RequestBody @Valid UserRegistrationRequest urf, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    return toJson(someResponse);
}
```

I wonder, what is the best way to log http request **body** and response body?
At the moment, I have custom json message converter and it logs a request body, before creating a bean out of json. and I use CustomTraceInterceptor to log a response body. Unfortunately, CustomTraceInterceptor doesn't allow to log request body.

Any advice for better solutions would be highly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Write a JEE filter (or a spring variant of a filter) and perform logging in that.

Answer (score 3):

Extend [HandlerInterceptorAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html), and override `postHandle`. Which has [request and response injected](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html#postHandle%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20java.lang.Object,%20org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView%29) into it.

You can also use `new HttpServletResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response)` which has a more friendly api, and spring probably has even nicer wrapper as well ...

Comment: And how I get response body?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter()

Comment: And to enable the interceptor with JavaConfig, in your @Configuration which implements WebMvcConfigurer (usually by way of extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter) , add     \@Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor());
    }